# Javascript regular expression if no digit specified before the period (.)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried following expression which works fine to allow only 2 decimal places:

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

But it's not considering the value like ".34" or ".5" as there isn't any digit before the period.
How can I update my expression so that, it should take digit "0" before period if nothing is specified before period.
so .34 => 0.34 with valid 2 decimal places expression.

Comment: Do you just want to match `.05` or add a  zero if there is none?

Comment: Zero if there is none before the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\d*\.?\d{1,2}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEALOK/7)

---

If you want to format decimal numbers up to 2 decimal points then use `toFixed`:

```
var n = ".34";
var str = parseFloat(n).toFixed(2) // will do rounding as well
//=> 0.34
```

Comment: Thanks for optimized solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use * instead of +

```
^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

+: Matches 1 or more of the preceding token.

*: Matches 0 or more of the preceding token.

Comment: This will allow empty input also

Comment: is true, the optional should be in the dot